# More Digits in Irrational Numbers

Tags: python, string, square-root

```
>>> str(1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799073247846210703885038753432764157273501384623091229702)
'1.41421356237'
```

Is there a way I can make str() record more digits of the number into the string? I don't understand why it truncates by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> from decimal import *
>>> Decimal('1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799073247846210703885038753432764157273501384623091229702')
Decimal('1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799073247846210703885038753432764157273501384623091229702')
```

The `float` literal is truncated by default to fit in the space made available for it (i.e. it's not because of `str`):

```
>>> 1.41421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537694807317667973799073247846210703885038753432764157273501384623091229702
1.4142135623730951
```

If you need more decimal places use [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) instead.

Answer (score 5):

Python's floating point numbers use double precision only, which is 64 bits. They simply cannot represent (significantly) more digits than you're seeing.

If you need more, have a look at the built-in [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module, or the [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/) package.

Answer (score 1):

The Python compiler is truncating; your float literal has more precision than can be represented in a C double. Express the number as a string in the first place if you need more precision.

Answer (score 0):

That's because it's converting to a float. It's not the conversion to the string that's causing it.
You should use decimal.Decimal for representing such high precision numbers.